# XML command line tool postgres

Tags: bash, cron, xml, database

I have an XML files to read and load into database daily at night (cron)
So i planed to do this in a batch.
Is there any command line tool to :
1. Create a postgres schema using an XSD file?
2. Transform an XML file into SQL commands for postgres?

Any other solution is welcome.

Comment: Better as this question in [dba][1] also


  [1]: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate SQL commands to import your file using xmlstarlet.

[Here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/220839-reading-xml-bash-importing-mysql.html) is an example.

Comment: I see. The example is for MYSQL but i can do the same for postgres. What about the schema creation?